# How to clear memory when loading a lot of csv files in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to aggregate some data (column names etc.) about a very large dataset. For that I am importing a whole bunch of delimited files (~100 Mbits each, 15GBs in total). My idea was to iterate through the directory that contains all the files, and clear the memory using `gc.collect()` at the end of each iteration to avoid Memory Errors.

This is my code:

```
import gc
import pandas as pd

path = "Data/Files/"
files = os.listdir(path)

num_lst = []
pre_lst = []
sub_lst = []
tag_lst = []

for file in files:

    num_fd = open(str(path + file + "/" + "num.txt"), encoding='utf8', errors = 'backslashreplace')
    pre_fd = open(str(path + file + "/" + "pre.txt"), encoding='utf8', errors = 'backslashreplace')
    sub_fd = open(str(path + file + "/" + "sub.txt"), encoding='utf8', errors = 'backslashreplace')
    tag_fd = open(str(path + file + "/" + "tag.txt"), encoding='utf8', errors = 'backslashreplace')

    num = pd.read_csv(num_fd, sep='\t', engine="python", error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False)
    pre = pd.read_csv(pre_fd, sep='\t', engine="python", error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False)
    sub = pd.read_csv(sub_fd, sep='\t', engine="python", error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False)
    tag = pd.read_csv(tag_fd, sep='\t', engine="python", error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False)

    num_lst.append([file] + list(num.columns.values))
    pre_lst.append([file] + list(pre.columns.values))
    sub_lst.append([file] + list(sub.columns.values))
    tag_lst.append([file] + list(tag.columns.values))

    del num, pre, sub, tag
    del num_fd, pre_fd, sub_fd, tag_fd
    gc.collect()
```

However, despite the effort I am getting a:

*MemoryError: Unable to allocate 26.1 MiB for an array with shape (3420083,) and data type uint64*

after about 10-12 iterations of the loop. Note that I am running this on a system with 16GB of RAM. Could it be that the memory is not actually cleared at the end of each loop! If so, how would I achieve this?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you are still storing all the data in the lists defined above the for loop. Only thing that gets freed is the pandas code that reads/processes the data.

Comment: @JanMatějka: OP only keeps the column names in those lists...

Comment: Pandas and its underlying numpy companion intensively use C code for performance reasons. Still for performance reasons, they are known to tweak the Global Interprocess Lock from Python. I would not be surprised that they have their own memory allocation system independant of the global `gc`. Anyway they are really great tools, but they intensively use memory and often assume that *there should be enough memory*. To process files greater than available memory, I would not use pandas but the good old `csv` module that can process a file one line at a time...

Comment: ... I agree that it does not answer the question, hence only posted as a comment :-)

Comment: how many cores are on your machine? before you start consuming the file data, how much virtual memory is the python program sitting at?

Comment: do all of the files for each file type have a uniform schema (column names)?

Comment: @skullgoblet1089 My program has 6 cores. How do I check the amout of virtual memory allocated to python? I do not know the schema. Trying to find that out, is part of the reason I am running that code.

Comment: Thanks Leo. numpy will by default allocate itself an internal thread pool in cpython process that hosts python. the memory allocated to the thread pool is proportional to the number of cores on the machine. so on machines with large number of cores, its possible to blow out just on init if you dont change the default settings. 6 cores not enough to trigger this behavior.

Comment: To help you monitor memory usage, consider a library like: https://pypi.org/project/memprof/.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple ideas, if you just want to collect summary info about each file:

Setup: get the file names (I used `pathlib` instead of `os`):

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

path = '.'
filenames = [f for f in Path(path).glob('*.csv')]
```

Extract headers (only) from each file.  Just read the first line of each file, as @Serge Ballesta noted above:

```
headers = dict()

for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, 'rt') as csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        line = next(csv_reader)
    headers[filename] = line
```

Or, get summary info about each CSV file, and store in a dictionary.  Each key is a filename.  Each corresponding value is itself a dictionary, with summary stats of interest.

```
summary = dict()

for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, 'rt') as handle:
        df = pd.read_csv(handle)
        summary[filename] = {
            'shape': df.shape,
            'columns': df.columns,
        }
```

There is only one open file at a time, and I'm assuming the summary stats for a file are a small fraction of the file itself.

Comment: Leo if you combine jsmart and my answer together you get a winning combination. jsmart's snippets to derive a uniform schema most critical part of solution.

Answer (score 0):

If each file type has a uniform schema for all of its instances, then advantage of using pandas to help you join the data in memory (handling the consolidation of column headers in a single DataFrame after you have collected all of the data in a list) is lost. In that scenario, recommend to simply not accumulate the data in lists, rather append each new iteration of file data to files that act as accumulators. This way, the most you have in memory is the hwm of the largest files that you had to store in memory to parse to DataFrame format during a single iteration.

```py
import pandas as pd

path = "Data/Files/"
files = os.listdir(path)

num_fp = './num-consol.csv'
pre_fp = './pre-consol.csv'
sub_fp = './sub-consol.csv'
tag_fp = './tag-consol.csv'


def accumulate(fp, df):
    df.to_csv(fp, mode='a', encoding='utf8', header=False, index=False)
  

for file in files:

    num_fd = open(str(path + file + "/" + "num.txt"), encoding='utf8', errors = 'backslashreplace')
    pre_fd = open(str(path + file + "/" + "pre.txt"), encoding='utf8', errors = 'backslashreplace')
    sub_fd = open(str(path + file + "/" + "sub.txt"), encoding='utf8', errors = 'backslashreplace')
    tag_fd = open(str(path + file + "/" + "tag.txt"), encoding='utf8', errors = 'backslashreplace')

    num = pd.read_csv(num_fd, sep='\t', engine="python", error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False)
    pre = pd.read_csv(pre_fd, sep='\t', engine="python", error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False)
    sub = pd.read_csv(sub_fd, sep='\t', engine="python", error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False)
    tag = pd.read_csv(tag_fd, sep='\t', engine="python", error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False)

    accumulate(num_fp, num)
    accumulate(pre_fp, pre)
    accumulate(sub_fp, sub)
    accumulate(tag_fp, tag)
```